Email sent from command line not received until I switch to the sending user
I'm using this command from the macOS command line (also in various scripts) to send email:
printf 'From:me@mydomain.com\nTo:me@mydomain.com\nSubject:Test\nTest.' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f me@mydomain.com -r me@mydomain.com me@mydomain.com
Most of the time it works fine, but a couple of times each week, these emails don't get to the recipient.
I've discovered that these emails will be sent if I use the macOS user switcher to switch to the user that sent the emails. As soon as I switch, the emails are sent.
Normally, there's no monitor connected to the Mac, and I access it remotely. I always have a remote session open, but logged in as a different user than the one that sends the email.
Connecting to the Mac using SSH doesn't help, even if it's as the sending user. I can send test emails but they just pile up somewhere. Once I've actually switched to the sending user, everything starts working normally. Subsequent test emails sent from the CLI are received normally.
I've checked the various display and power settings, and everything is configured to keep the machine awake.
